# Translate IF-ELSE statement of MS SQL to SnowFlake

Tags: if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, insert-update

I have a MS SQL query like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableDescription WHERE "viewname"='abc')
UPDATE TableDescription 
SET "viewname"='abc' , "description"='description xyz' 
WHERE "viewname"='abc'
ELSE
INSERT INTO TableDescription ("viewname","description") VALUES('abc','description xyz')
```

And I would like to translate the above MS SQL query to a coresponding query that works on SnowFlake but not sure how I can do it :(
Could someone please give me a hint?
Thanks so much
Hanh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) could be used:

```
MERGE TableDescription t
USING (SELECT 'abc' AS "viewname", 'description xyz' AS "description")s
  ON t."viewname" = s."viewname"
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET t."viewname"   = s."viename",
                t."description"= s."description
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT("viewname", "description")
     VALUES (s."viewname", s."description");
```